# Generate simulations using variogram with given mean and standard deviation

Tags: r, kriging, gstat, variogram, simulation

I am trying to generate simulations using variogram using the R code below

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

# Call data
points <- read.csv("data_xyz.csv")
coords <- read.csv("coords.csv")

# Create spatial dataframe
spatial_df <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=cbind(points$x, points$y), 
                                         data=points, 
                                         proj4string=sp::CRS(projargs="+init=epsg:2193"))


# Create new spatial data
newspatial_df <- data.frame(points$x, points$y)
colnames(newspatial_df)[1] <- 'x'
colnames(newspatial_df)[2] <- 'y'
newspatial_df <- sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=cbind(newspatial_df$x, newspatial_df$y), 
                                             data=newspatial_df, 
                                             proj4string=sp::CRS(projargs="+init=epsg:2193"))

# Calculate emperical variogram
var <- gstat::variogram(object=z~1, locations=spatial_df)
fit_var <- gstat::fit.variogram(
  object=var,
  model=gstat::vgm('Gau')
)


# Plot variogram
ori_pred = variogramLine(fit_var, maxdist = max(var$dist))  # Generate variogramline for plotting
plot_ori_var = ggplot(var, aes(x = dist, y = gamma)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = ori_pred) # Plot using ggplot

# plot_ori_var # uncomment if you want to see the plot

# Generate unconditional simulations
z.sims <- gstat::krige(z~1, loc=NULL, newdata=newspatial_df, model=fit_var, nmax=100, nsim=50, beta=0, dummy=T)

# Remove coords.x and coords.y and add distance column
z_df <- as.data.frame(z.sims)
newz.sims.nocoords <- z_df[-c(1,2)]
newz.sims <- cbind(newz.sims.nocoords, coords['distance'])


# Plot data
data_melt <- reshape2::melt(newz.sims, id='distance')
gfg_plot <- ggplot(data_melt,            
                   aes(x = distance,
                       y = value,
                       color=variable)) +  geom_line()
# gfg_plot # uncomment if you want to see the plot

# Calculate mean and standard deviation for each row
data_mean <- apply(newz.sims.nocoords, 1, mean)
data_sd <- apply(newz.sims.nocoords, 1, sd)


# Plot mean (red line) and standard deviation (pink area) - error plot
plot(coords[, 1], data_mean,
     ylim=range(c(data_mean - data_sd, data_mean + data_sd)),
     pch=19, xlab="Distances", ylab="Mean +/- SD", col='red',
     main="Scatter plot with std.dev error bars"
)
red2 <- adjustcolor("red", alpha.f=0.25)
arrows(coords[, 1], data_mean - data_sd, 
       coords[, 1], data_mean + data_sd, length=0.05, angle=90, code=3, col=red2)
```

The final plot (error plot) is as below

[image]

As you can see, the mean line (red line) of the data close to 0 because I can specify the mean for simulated dataset as 0 by stating `beta=0` but I do not know where to state the standard deviation (looks like the standard deviation in the plot larger than 2). I am looking for something like `krige(z~1, loc=NULL, newdata=newspatial_df, model=fit_var, nmax=100, nsim=50, beta=0, sd=1, dummy=T)` where `sd=1` means standard deviation equals to 1.

The `data_xyz` can be downloaded [here](https://pastebin.com/mRPuHyHT) and the `coords.csv` [here](https://pastebin.com/c4SbRM7R) (please change format file to csv after downloading)

Comment: Can you make a sample data set or use an existing one so we have something in common to work with?

Comment: @Spacedman: Yes, I have added more information.